# Not able to get the correct div to get the data from the table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scraping data off https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html After a lot of hit and trials, I am still not able to identify how to get the data from the table?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
container = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'mainPage'})
print(container)
```

Comment: Could you specify which table you meant?

Comment: @SIM It is the table on the website which is under 'Decision Tracker'. The one which has the decision, school, date, gmatscore, username and all

Comment: There are three tabs `real time updates`, `summary by school` and `interview debriefs` in there. Which tab produces that data? You question is still too broad.

Comment: I think `real time updates` but you have use json data from xhr as data is dynamic appearing so hard to fetch from `bs4`

Comment: Yes, real time updates. Sorry about the confusion @SIM.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh wow, how do i go about it then? Any tips? I just wanna do it for practice and its seems so weird

Comment: Okay  go to Chrome developer and than xhr reload site and you find url from find which link contain table data and copy that link but requests module is not allowing to fetch data beacause of authenitcation if you can not find here it is [url](https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates?limit=100&offset=49&year=all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to practice, take a look at `Developer Toos -> Network -> XHR` and grab the update endpoint:

```
https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates?limit=50&year=all
```

and use it to get the current data.

Here's how:

```python
import requests

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers.update(
        {
            "referer": "https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
        }
    )
    _ = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html")
    endpoint = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates?limit=50&year=all").json()
    for item in endpoint["statistics"]:
        print(item)
```

This will output a list of dictionaries, which are in fact your table. You can then access any key from it.

```
{'id': '194901', 'user_id': '273781', 'applicant_type': 'regular', 'round_id': '4236', 'status_id': '9', 'school_id': '5', 'school_title': 'Booth', 'program_id': '11', 'program_type': '1', 'date': '2021-05-24 23:56:46', 'seconds_ago': '511', 'country': None, 'state': None, 'gmat_quant': None, 'gmat_verbal': None, 'gmat_total': None, 'gmat_modified': None, 'gre_quant': None, 'gre_verbal': None, 'gre_total': None, 'gre_modified_time': None, 'ea_quant': None, 'ea_verbal': None, 'ea_ir': None, 'ea_total': None, 'ea_modified_time': None, 'cat_india_percentile': None, 'cat_india_total': None, 'cat_india_modified_time': None, 'industry': None, 'we': None, 'gpa': None, 'accepted_via': 'phone', 'scholarship': '1', 'user_colour': '', 'truncate_username': '0', 'user_name': 'binhtbc'}
```

Or you can just dump the response to `pandas dataframe`. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(endpoint["statistics"])
print(df.head(10))
```

Output:

```
       id  user_id applicant_type  ... user_colour truncate_username    user_name
0  194901   273781        regular  ...                             0      binhtbc
1  183152   643532        regular  ...                             0         AG23
2  194061     None        regular  ...      2a2a2a                 0      private
3  192923  1034549        regular  ...                             0  RicardoLima
4  193383  1034549        regular  ...                             0  RicardoLima
5  194900  1130431        regular  ...                          None          VFA
6  177937   876400        regular  ...      F87431                 0   icanhazmba
7  194899  1128750        regular  ...                          None     Amanda29
8  194898  1128002        regular  ...                          None      Raydiaz
9  193974  1021516        regular  ...                             0    Kurathore
```

And, if you feel like it, save this as `.csv` file:

```
    df.to_csv("your_table_data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how it should be. To get the required content in json, it is necessary to send requests to the main url first as it helps store the cookies. However, you still need to have a retry counter in place as this site throws connection error very frequently.

Comment: @SIM true, the endpoint is moody when it comes to responding but an exponential backoff should do it. However, this is beyond the scope of the question and my answer. Anyhow, thanks for the feedback! Appreciate it.

Comment: @baduker Thank you so much! what will be the way to get more data from the table? As in the old entries which only sho when we click 'show more' at the end of website. And a little unsure on how to get the application status, which is at the very left of each entry denoted by a coloured dot

Comment: @Aditya your follow-up questions are beyond the scope of one answer. However, you'd need to update the endpoint with a `limit` and `offset` values. Also, you'd have to have a mapping of the `status_id` key to get a more descriptive info. Best to ask a new question.

Comment: Got it, I should do that, thank you so much for all the help